# ¿porque me sale null en la salida de este codigo?

Tags: java, java-swing

son estudiante y tengo este problema no se porque me sale el null despues de cada System.out.println(Jose.getobservarPlaneta()); oy System.out.println(Jose.getagujeroNegro());

[image: Es la clase de astronauta]
[image: Es la clase ejecutable]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. **No pongas capturas del código, coloca el código por favor**.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estas imprimiendo el retorno de tus funciones `Jose.getobservarPlaneta()` y `Jose.getagujeroNegro()`, como estas no tienen retorno tus impresiones son `null`.

Para que estos null no te aparezcan solo debes ejecutar las funciones:

```
Jose.getobservarPlaneta();
Jose.getagujeroNegro();
```

Con este cambio ya no tendrás esos null.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código no devuelve nada entonces estas intentando imprimir un `void`

podrías cambiar tus métodos a que retornen un String

```
String getObservarPlaneta(){
  return "TEXTO";
}
```

o simplemente llamar a la función sin el `System.out.println`

Por ejemplo:

`Jose.getObervarPlaneta();`

Answer (score -1):

Debes poner los setter que te faltan.
Jose.setObservarPlaneta("aquí tu respuesta");
Jose.setAgujeroNegro("aquí tu respuesta");

Answer (score -2):

Los métodos de la clase `Astronauta` (las clases deberían tener nombres que comienzan en mayúscula) no inicializan los valores de los atributos `observarPlaneta` y `agujeroNegro`. Así pues, cuando instancias a Jose, esos atributos tienen valor null. Por lo tanto, vas a imprimir null. Tu código hace lo que le dices que haga.